# Solving system of equations to gain desired step response

Tags: matlab, plot, equation, ode45

I need to obtain the values of a, b and c in the following equations so that the step response of the system matches that of the figure below.

```
x_dot = a*x + b+u;
y = c*x;
```

Where x_dot is the first derivative of x.

[image: Figure 1: Desired output]

I have been trying to achieve this through Matlab and have so far achieved the following, using just arbitrary values for a, b and c for testing purposes:

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

a=1;
b=2;
c=3;

tspan = [0:0.01:12];

x_dot = a*x+b*xu;
x = (a*x^2)/2 + b*u*x;
y = c*x;

f = @(t,x) [a*x(1)+b*x(2); c*x(1)];
[t, xa] = ode45(f,tspan,[0,0]);

plot(t,xa(:,1));
```

Comment: Have you got the System Identification toolbox? If so, have a look at [this video](http://uk.mathworks.com/videos/estimating-state-space-and-polynomial-models-68898.html). Or if you have the optimization toolbox, you can create a cost function with the least square difference of the error between the predicted step response and the desired one, and try to minimise that by tuning the parameters.

Comment: Is the `y` (which I assume is `x(2)` in the code) also supposed to be a time derivative in the first block of code such that you include its right-hand side in the `ode45` call?  What is `u` and what is `xu` (which is absent from the system you posted)?  And what information do you have access to that will allow you to match the figure: only the figure or the initial slope or the terminal values and slope or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This certainly sounds like a parameter estimation problem as already hinted. You want to minimise the error between the outcome modelled using your ode and the values in your graph (fitting your three parameters a,b and c to the data).

A first step is to write an error function that takes the ode output values and compares how close it is to the data values (sum of least squares error for instance).

Then you have to search through a range of a,b,c values (which may be a large search space) and you pick the set of (a,b,c) which minimise your error function (i.e. get as close to your graph as possible).

Many search/optimisation strategies exist (.. e.g. genetic algorithm/etc.).

Please Note that the parameters are elements of real numbers(which includes negative values and extremely large or small values), the large search space is usually what makes these problems difficult to solve.
                                                                                         Also I think you have to be careful of initial conditions e.g. [0,0] doesn't seem to lead to interesting results. (try a = -0.5,b=0.2 and c=-0.00000001, with IC of [0,10] as below)

```
clc;
close all;
clear all;

a=-0.5;
b=0.2;
c=-0.00000001;

tspan = [0:0.01:12];

f = @(t,x) [a*x(1)+b*x(2); c*x(1)];
[t, xa] = ode45(f,tspan,[0,10]);

plot(t,xa);
hold on 
plot(t,4)
```

Here 10 is the starting point of the green line and blue line starts at 0. What I would also note is that the IC change the results.. so there any many possible solutions for a,b,c given IC.

Looks interesting.. good luck.

[image: ode plot]